# selectable sql tables with dropdownlist in C# web form. via gridview's updatecommand and deletecommand

Tags: c#, sql, .net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a selectable SQL tables with dropdownlist in C# web form.but  I am using gridview's `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand`. When I change the table also I have to change the `SqlCommand` text too.

I want to match it like

```
update [selected.table] 
where [selected.value](from 2nd dropdownlist) = @id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could tab into the OnRowUpdating event and do something like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string updateQuery = string.Format("UPDATE {0} SET yourcolumns = @params WHERE {1} = @id", selected.table, selected.value);
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = updateQuery;
}
```

I am not entirely sure, but this could possibly point you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes this is want I wanted to see thank you very much

Comment: Nice I could help, it would be nice if you could mark my reply as the answer if it solved your problem